# Convert a row in a table to a column

Tags: awk, sed

here is my 1.file (The delimiter is "\t")

```
 ot1     a       a,b,c,d,e
 ot2     b       b,c,q
 ot3     c       c,f,g
 ot4     e       a,g,e
```

i want to get the 2.file (The delimiter is "\t")

```
 ot1     a       a
 ot1     a       b
 ot1     a       c
 ot1     a       d
 ot1     a       e
 ot2     b       b
 ot2     b       c
 ot2     b       q
 ot3     c       c
 ot3     c       f
 ot3     c       g
 ot4     e       a
 ot4     e       g
 ot4     e       e
```

fisrtly, i have try the  "sed -i "s/,/\n/g", but i don't konw what to do next?
appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F\\t 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {n=split($3,aa,",");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {$3=aa[i]; printf "%s\n" $0 }}'
```

First tabulation delimiter need double escape

then split the 3th token and get the number of elements in splitted array

then replace 3th token in loop with splited elements and print

Comment: Minor nit-pick - you're having to escape the ```\``` in ```\t``` because you aren't quoting it. Always single quote all shell strings (including scripts) unless you **need** to double quote them to let the shell expand variables or **need** to remove the quotes to let the shell do globbing, etc., see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. If you follow that rule then you'd write `awk -F'\t' ...` and then you wouldn't need to add the extra ```\``` to stop the shell from interpreting ```\t``` as you invited it to do by removing the `'`s.

Comment: awk -F\\t 'BEGIN {OFS=FS} {n=split($3,aa,",");for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {$3=aa[i]; printf "%s\n" $0 }}'  when i run this in first time， i meet the erro  ”fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string“    i reviewed the script and found which lose the ”，”  in  "print “%s\n" ,$0"

Comment: @loki change `printf "%s\n" $0` to just `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Miller would work here:

```
mlr --tsv -N nest --explode --values --across-records --nested-fs "," -f 3 1.file > 2.file
```

Explanation

`--tsv` - use tab-separated values file format for in- and output

`-N` - use numeric IDs to address fields, instead of header names

`nest` - data is nested

`--explode` - explode nested data

`--values` - nested data are individual values

`--across-records` - write out exploded data into separate records

`--nested-fs` - field separator for nested values

`-f 3` - explode based on field no. 3